# User independent data import

Tags: r, data-import

Say X and Y are working on a `project` which requieres a file `data.csv`. They have some common file within a cloud service named `main.R`. Now assume that within `main.R` X and Y respectively are importing data via

```
# uncomment first line if you are X, otherwise uncomment second line
# data <- read.csv("C:/User/X/Documents/cloud/project/data.csv")
# data <- read.csv("C:/User/Y/Desktop/cloud/project/data.csv")
```

Instead of uncomment one of the lines depending who is running the script I'd like to have one command in total which is universal and referes to the part of the file path which they have in common, say,

```
data <- read.csv(".../cloud/project/data.csv")
```

Any idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: if you set your working directory beforehand, say via `setwd("C:/User/X")` you can then use `read.cvs("project/data.csv")`. is this what you want?

Comment: No, because the path still depens on X. If Y you would run the program, there would be an error message indicating that the path refers to X.

Comment: How about `read.csv(paste0("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["effective_user"],"/project/data.csv"))` ?

Comment: Ok, you got my point. But I think I didn't express what I was really looking for. There is still some other user dependent stuff in front of the `/project/data.csv'. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#check if directory exists
dataDir <-
  if(dir.exists(paste0("C:/Users/",Sys.info()["effective_user"], "/Documents/cloud/project/"))){
    paste0("C:/Users/", Sys.info()["effective_user"],"/Documents/cloud/project/")
  } else if(dir.exists(paste0("C:/Users/", Sys.info()["effective_user"],"/Desktop/cloud/project/"))) {
    paste0("C:/Users/", Sys.info()["effective_user"],"/Desktop/cloud/project/")
  }


#if exists then read in
if(!is.null(dataDir)){ read.csv(paste0(dataDir,"data.csv")) }
```